# Renderizado de endpoint en React

Tags: reactjs

me gustaria consultarles si existe alguna manera de poder acceder al array de "detail" y luego pasar cada uno dinamicamente a otro endpoint para que se renerice en la pag articulo:

Lo estuve intentando hacer con un state pero me sale "undefined"

```
{cardCategory.map(card => (
        <div className='categorias-card' key={card.categoryId}>
          <img src={card.imagen} alt={card.Topic} />
          <Link to={{
            pathname: `/articulos/${card.topic}`,
            state: { detail: card.detail }
          }}>
          Título: {card.topic}</Link>
          <p>Descripción: {card.detail}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

const ItemListIdArt = ( ) => {

```
const location = useLocation();
console.log('location', location)
```

```
Osea la idea es que la hacer click en "topic" se renderizen los elementos dentro del "detail"

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnXUk.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvMU7.png
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kHZf.png
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, agrega el componente entero y de ser posible explica mejor que es lo que quieres que ocurra.